# Multiple monitors quit working/not displayed in 'Displays' (CentOS 8)

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, centos, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg

I have been using the following kernels from my GRUB menu:

`CentOS Linux (4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64) 8` // broke it all

`CentOS Linux (4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64) 8` // problem

`CentOS Linux (4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64) 8 (Core)` // works

`CentOS Linux (4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64) 8 (Core)` // works

`CentOS Linux (0-rescure-blahHash ) 8 (Core)` // not tested

`System setup` //lolwut

on my CentOS 8 desktop/server box, with a nvidia 750 Ti, and 260 GTX (will not buy nvidia in the future).

*btw what does the '(Core)' mean? core build?*

I had issues with the `Standard (Wayland)` login/DisplayManager/Desktop Environment (DE) option only working on the two monitors on the 750 Ti. 3rd was black, would not show windows, but would show the mouse (weird and hard to google). Eventually after messing with confs, positioning, GRUB options, etc, changing the DE to `Standard (X11 display server) on Xorg`, worked. All 3 monitors displayed 1920x1080 with enough performance for non-gaming (untested) desktop productivity, using default non-proprietary Noveau drivers. I stuck with this, security implications of X11 aside (though that is a concern). The 260 GTX 9/10 times has its fan at screaming 100%, the other time, it is at 0, it overheats, and system freezes. It appears the kernel cannot read its temperature sensor right or something, but does display and I can wear earmuffs/headphone.

**Problems:**

When updating to: `CentOS Linux (4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64) 8`, only the center monitor on the 750 Ti worked, and only at 1024x768 :(. Shows 'Unknown Display' as the only display in 'Displays'. Reverting to `CentOS Linux (4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64) 8 (Core)` fixes the problem. A few weeks went by using the old kernel, I figured I should try updating before posting here. `CentOS Linux (4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64) 8` has the same issue, and reverting to previous kernels does not undo the change! I even opened `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` and changed `installation_limit` to 6 kernels instead of 3, so it wouldn't touch the working ones.. unless it does anyway? Also the `Standard (Wayland)` login option/DM is gone, which if it is more secure, maybe I want to go back to at some point.

I hope this belongs here. should I also/instead post on Serverfault? I have been using ubuntu/debian linux for years, but typically on a laptop with one monitor, which always works and was sufficient for my Linux tasks. I am not going back to Windows after the abomination that was 8, 8.1, and then 10 -- not to mention cutting 7 support short (just realized CentOS 8 EOL is 2021, but 7's is 2024 :( ). I haven't had to dig into the guts of Linux much besides some casual Desktop Environment (DE) Experimentation, and new to CentOS/RHEL. I may be attributing too much to the kernel, when it is an issue with the Display Manager (DM), DE or something. Feel free to educate, I am here to learn linux, how to identify and fix problems, and make this a better product.

**Additional Details/trials:**

I set:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"`
to try and fix the fan issue on the 260 GTX. Implications, security/otherwise are unknown, but it was working before.

Trying to fix this myself, xrandr:

`() $ xrandr --listproviders`

> Providers: number : 0

`() $ xrandr -q`

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
> minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768 default
> connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm    1024x768 76.00*

which looks like a problem, but I can't revert to the old state since the old kernels still have this issue now that I loaded the very latest.

lspci shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2) 
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1) 
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT200 [GeForce GTX 260] (rev a1)
```

both cards detected.. okay.

lshw shows:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
..
            configuration: latency=0
```

aha! This shows 'UNCLAIMED' now, and the configuration is missing some things. It used to show:

`configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=1920,1080`

Also present are some weird entries:

```
*-graphics
   product: EFI VGA
   physical id: 2
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   capabilities: fb
   configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768

*-power UNCLAIMED
   description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   physical id: 1
   version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   capacity: 32768mWh
```

What looks to be a default/generic/unknown (?) display, and some weird power/battery entry? this is a desktop.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig (`pwmconfig`) used to show:

```
Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is acpitz
   hwmon1 is nouveau
   hwmon2 is nouveau
   hwmon3 is asus
   hwmon4 is coretemp
   hwmon5 is nct6791
```

but now only shows:

```
Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is acpitz
   hwmon1 is asus
   hwmon2 is coretemp
   hwmon3 is nct6791
```

.. missing the noveaus

though the 260 GTX fan is at a (relatively) nice ~40-50% instead of screaming at 100%

I re-ran sensors-detect, didn't seem to do anything.

lsmod did not seem to show me stuff that was useful, but I don't know my way around the kernel and its modules that well, so I may have missed something obvious.

opening /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 40.493] Build Operating System: 4.19.34-300.el7.x86_64
[ 40.493] Current Operating System: Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 1 17:16:16 UTC 2021 x86_64
[ 40.493] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/cl-00 ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-02 rd.lvm.lv=cl/00 rd.luks.uuid=luks-redactedUUID rd.lvm.lv=cl/02 rhgb quiet quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax
[ 40.493] Build Date: 04 January 2021 04:26:35PM
[ 40.493] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.8-6.1.el8_3
[ 40.493] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4

[ 40.493] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 40.493] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Mar 5 14:24:22 2021
[ 40.494] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 40.494] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 40.495] (==) No Layout section. Using the first Screen section.
[ 40.495] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 40.495] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 40.495] (**) | |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 40.495] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 40.495] (==) Automatically adding devices
...
[ 40.615] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 40.616] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 40.616] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 40.616] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
...
[ 40.736] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
[ 40.736] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[ 40.736] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[ 40.736] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
...
```

is something going wrong with some kind of blasted DRM?? argh nvidia. I cut out parts that don't look useful.

note that the owner of this log file is 'gdm' instead of my username, like the older Xorg log files, for some reason.

some people have suggested deleting:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf/d/20-intel.conf
```

(DNE for me)

and

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
    /xorg.conf.d/
```

but I am afraid to delete any progress I did/didn't make with Wayland, and the files worked fine before the kernel update.

I also heard I could try lightDM instead of GDM, or KDE plasma, but I had some issues there without the latest updates installed. Now that everything is broken, but latest versions, maybe I will try. I guess it could be worse and I could have zero display.

---

**to summarize:**

- issue with 260 GTX display not drawing windows, only mouse: temporarily resolved by logging in with 'Standard (X11 display server) on Xorg' instead of 'Standard (Wayland)', perhaps introducing critical security issues for convenience and productivity of 3rd monitor
- issue with 260 GTX fan speed in jet engine mode, perhaps due to kernel not reading temp sensor correctly
- more pressing issue with displays not working on first kernel update (4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64)
- critical issue with latest kernel update (4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64), breaking previous display configs/etc. whatever is going on for all others

- 260 GTX fan speed is only at ~50%, but won't display the screen

- Also, won't wake from standby anymore. Black screen requires restart.

This is noticeable at boot, the splash screen is now only visible on one monitor (with lower resolution) instead of mirroring on all 3.

Edit: just noticed my xorg log states it is running Build Operating System: 4.19.34-300.el7.x86_64, but is definitely running 4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64. This discrepancy seems to be visible in this user's arch: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251261

Sorry for the long post, but I tried to organize it and show what I have already tried with some result. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may have luck posting this over on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange!

Comment: thanks, posted. no result yet. Hoping to avoid a re-install.